# Fixed div bar will not appear on top even after z-indexing

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm currently modifying a Xenforo theme for my website and I'm having trouble with my header bar after I downloaded a new theme.

http://www.ausfifa.com/forums/index.php?forums/head-to-head.2/

If you scroll down the page, you'll notice that certain elements such as the search bar, breadcrumb arrows and mini avatars are appearing above my header bar.

I'm not sure why this is happening as I've set the header bar's z-index to 9999 and its position is fixed (when you scroll down after a certain point, javascript sets position = fixed). All the elements that are overlapping it have z-indices that are lower than 9999. The odd thing is, this wasn't an issue on my older theme and I never modified any CSS for it to start doing this.

This is the div which contains my header:

```
#header-menu-cont {
font-family: DIN-Cond;
font-size: 15pt;
min-width: 1000px;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 52px;
background: #333333;
z-index: 9999;
position: relative;
}
```

This is the mini avatar that overlaps my header:

```
.discussionListItem .posterAvatar .miniMe {
bottom: 1px;
left: 29px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
}
```

The search bar that overlaps my header:

```
#searchBar {
position: relative;
z-index: 52;
}
```

I've also tried setting a high z-index to all of the elements inside my header bar but it makes no difference.

Feel free to inspect any of the HTML in my website if you'd like to get more information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting Z-index you need to do this on the containing element not the ones inside it.

In your case the `#headerMover` div has `z-index:1;` applied to it.

If you take this out of your CSS or add a higher z-index on `#headerMover` it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
#headerMover, .footer, .footerLegal {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

You need to give the parent/container the z-index, not the elements inside it.